# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat - high memory usage

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have `t2.nano` (512MB RAM) Elastic Beanstalk instance but even after restart (app servers) and just few requests I start to receive `93 % of memory is in use.` warnings and then instance stops responding, until it reboots itself.

When I reboot the instance and run `watch -n 1 free -m` I get the following

```
Every 1.0s: free -m                                     Sat Aug 27 14:15:19 2016

             total   used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           491        485          5          0          6         91
-/+ buffers/cache:        387        103
Swap:            0          0          0
```

which means I have only ~100MB at my disposal, out of 512MB, or?

---

On my localhost everything works just fine. I'm looking for a memory leak but can't really tell where is the problem because on my dev machine everything works just fine (heap dump after few hundreds requests is usually <50MB).

I'm using `Tomcat 8` with `Java 8`, `Servlet 3.0` and `Hibernate + JPA`.

Not sure how to go about this?

Comment: How much memory does your localhost have and how much memory does t2.nano instance have?

Comment: 512MB. I also updated localhost explanation - memory doesn't go much above 50MB. Localhost is 8GB RAM.

Comment: Well, that is one tiny instance. 1) try modifying maximum memory allocation to  -Xms128m -Xmx128m 2) Can you try running it on t2.small, at least as an experiment?

Comment: I'm not sure 1) would work - I updated the answer with freshly-rebooted instance and `watch -n 1 free -m` command 2) will try although I'm expecting the same pattern (free memory just being decreased as requests are coming)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some swap space before deploy your application.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swapfile bs=1M count=512
mkswap /var/swapfile
chmod 0600 /var/swapfile
swapon /var/swapfile
```